# Python 2.7 server.socket timeout question

Tags: python, sockets, server, timeout

I have some python code that sometimes will block when a connection is opened up but no data is sent.  I understand why it is waiting for 64 bits or less of data. It will wait forever.  Is there a simple way to time out the connection if no data is received.  Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
    serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    serversocket.bind(('', port))
    serversocket.listen(5) # become a server socket, maximum 5 connections
    while 1:
        try:
            while 1:
               # print "Waiting for oonnection..."
                connection, address = serversocket.accept()
                buf = connection.recv(64)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `socket.settimeout(value)` where `value` is number of seconds.

```py
    serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    serversocket.bind(('', port))
    serversocket.listen(5) # become a server socket, maximum 5 connections

    while 1:
        try:
            while 1:
               # print "Waiting for oonnection..."
                connection, address = serversocket.accept()
                connection.settimeout(5) # Set 5 seconds timeout to receive 64 bytes of data

                buf = connection.recv(64)

        except socket.timeout:
            print("Timeout happened -- goting back to accept another connection")
```

Comment: Setting it on the server socket will timeout the accept. To timeout the receive it must be set on the accepted socket.

Comment: @user207421 I just changed the code and set timeout on connection